# How to run Azure Powershell Cmdlets in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

```
Install-Module AzureAD 
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username@dev.com", $password)
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Cred
```

This is my sample Azure Powershell script. I've run it through Windows PowerShell ISE. Is there any way to run Azure cmdlets using Visual Studio 2017? Or any Nuget Packages available for referencing the library for Azure Powershell commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional for PRADEEP. We could install the Powershell tool with Visual Studio Installer. We also could install it from VS extensions and updates.

[image]

After that we could create the PowerShell project and script. We also could debug and run the scrpits in the VS.

[image]

**Note:** If you want to install Module, then we need to run the VS with **administrator rights**, or will get the error info `Administrator rights are required to install modules`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can install [PowerShell Tools from the Visual Studio Installer](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/poshtools/wiki/Installing-PowerShell-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-2017) as an individual component or as a part of the "Azure development" workload.

**To install PowerShell Tools as an individual component:**

1. Click the "Individual components" tab.
2. List itemScroll to the "Code tools" section.
3. Check "PowerShell tools".
4. Click "Install" or "Modify" to apply the change.

[image]

After installing click on View => Other Windows => PowerShell Interactive Window => and run your cmdlet:

[image]

Comment: Is their a way to run Azure Powershell commands in app service and deployed in a serverless config? Thanks

Comment: @ArielLarisma App Service is very different from VM hosting. In App Service, you never get direct access to the VM, and there is generally no way that you can run any script that affects the VM at a global level.